# ConcurrentConsumers not created using DefaultMessageListenerContainer but using maximumActiveSessionsPerConnection on PooledConnectionFactory

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-jms

I have following Java class. When used with `CachingConnectionFactory` it creates configured number of `ConcurrentConsumers` set on `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. However if `PooledConnectionFactory` is used instead of `CachingConnectionFactory`, it just creates `concurrentConsumers` equals to `maximumActiveSessionPerConnection` set on `PooledConnectionFactory` instead of number of `concurrentConsumers` set on `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

How can I make sure the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` uses multiple connections/Sessions provided by `PooledConnectionFactory` and create configured number of `concurrentConsumer` provided to `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`. Below is the simple example to check the same.

```
    import javax.jms.Session;

    import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
    import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
    import org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory;
    import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;

    public class ActiveMQMainTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String queueUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616";
            ActiveMQQueue queue = new ActiveMQQueue("request.queue");

            final ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(queueUrl);

            PooledConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new PooledConnectionFactory();
            pooledConnectionFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            pooledConnectionFactory.setCreateConnectionOnStartup(false);
            pooledConnectionFactory.setMaxConnections(5);
            pooledConnectionFactory.setMaximumActiveSessionPerConnection(100);
            pooledConnectionFactory.start();

            // CachingConnectionFactory pooledConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

            DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(pooledConnectionFactory);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setDestination(queue);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setConcurrentConsumers(5);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5 * 2);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setSessionTransacted(true);
            JmsMessageListener messageListener = new JmsMessageListener();
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(messageListener);
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.afterPropertiesSet();
            defaultMessageListenerContainer.start();


            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 * 60 * 10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DMLC` uses a shared connection by default (when there's no transaction manager). It can be disabled using:

```
dmlc.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
```

You should also normally have `setSessionTransacted(true)` with the DMLC, to avoid the possibility of losing messages (with the DMLC, messages are ack'd before the listener is invoked), using local transactions, the ack won't go to the broker until the listener exits normally.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Another doubt, by setting CacheLevel to NONE DMLC doesn't use shared connection. However as I am planning pre-create connections in PooledConnectionFactory, will DMLC be using the connections created by PooledConnectionFactory?

Comment: Yes; of course; the container knows nothing about the connection factory or how it allocates connections to clients. It just asks for a connection. Bear in mind that pooling connections does not make much sense for a listener container because the consumers are generally long-lived. Pooling makes sense for short-lived consumers/producers. Note that each consumer will get its own connection so the sessions per connection is likely moot (I don't know the internals of the PCF). If you want to hand out the same connection to multiple consumers, but not all, you will likely need your own factory.

Comment: After incorporating your suggestions things were working fine. But when I restarted the broker, consumers created by DMLC haven't recovered and my server stopped consuming messages. Is there any other setting which needs to be set on DMLC to activemq recovery. I have updated the code as per your suggestions.